# Ajax post FormData and the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this form:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<div class='col-sm-6' style="padding-left:0px;" >
    <form action="/main/" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <br>

      <div> <input type="text" name="description" id="id_description" /> </div>
      <div> <input type="file" name="image" id="id_image" /> </div>


      <button type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button>
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Gem" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This successfully sends the form and it is valid on the server side. But I can´t access the image from the form on the server.

```
<script>
    var frm = $('#my_form');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("error")
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

This solution sends the FormData with the image file, but it does not include the other form data and the form is not valid on the server side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#my_form');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            "image",
            document.getElementById("id_image").files[0]
        );

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("error")
            }
       });
   });


</script>
```

Is there a way to send both the file and the other form  dara at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try passing `this` to `FormData` Also, you were setting `type` twice.

```
var frm = $('#my_form');
frm.submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(e);

  var formData = new FormData(this);

  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function (data) {
      console.log("success")
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log("error")
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last block using `formData` is only appending the file. This is why `data` only contains the file no other form data. Be sure to fully populate `formData` first.